# Angular Jasmine unit test with AJAX data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ng-grid

I have a service, DataContext which returns me a set of data that I want to use in my controller.  This data is used by an ng-grid directive.  The options for the grid are supplied by GridOptionsService.

All of this works fine, but I'm trying to write a unit test to check and see if everything's working.

```
describe('Grid display test', function() {
    var $scope, elm, oCtrl;

    beforeEach(module('ngGrid'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $controller,DataContext,GridOptionsService) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $scope.gridOptions = GridOptionsService.getGridOptions('documents');
        $scope = $rootScope;
        elm = angular.element('<div ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>');

        oCtrl = $controller('Repository',{$scope: $scope});
        $compile(elm)($scope)
        DataContext.getDocuments().then(function(data){
            $scope.myData = data;
            console.log('here are the grid options: ')
            console.log($scope.gridOptions);
        })
    }));

    it('should display rows',function(done){
        inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $controller, DataContext,GridOptionsService){
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                DataContext.getDocuments().then(function(data){
                    expect(data.length).toBe(1000);
                    done();
                })
            })
        })
    })
});
```

DataContext.getDocuments returns a promise and I use that to set the `myData` variable of the controller.  This data is the data for the grid. 
`$scope.gridOptions = GridOptionsService.getGridOptions('documents');`

gridOptions is simply a JS object returned from a service.  When I run the test I get the error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DataContextProvider <- DataContext`

All of the scripts that should be included in the spec runner are, and the code definitely works, but I just don't know how to test it.

How can I test AJAX code that changes the appearance of my DOM with Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking out your custom dependencies for your Jasmine test. The [$injector:unpr] results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. You can use $provide to register components with the injector. Try to add something like...

```
  beforeEach(function () {

      mockDependency = {
          getDataSet: function () {
              return 'mockDataSet';
          }
      };

      module(function ($provide) {
          $provide.value('DataContext', mockDependency);
      });

  });
```

Here's the documentation for $provide...https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide

Hope that helps